# Where is flowers parquet dataset in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, parquet, databricks-community-edition

I am working on this notebook. https://databricks.com/notebooks/simple-aws/petastorm-spark-converter-pytorch.html

I tried running the first line

```
df = spark.read.parquet("/databricks-datasets/flowers/parquet") \
  .select(col("content"), col("label_index")) \
  .limit(1000)
```

However I got this error

```
 Path does not exist: dbfs:/databricks-datasets/flowers/parquet;
```

I am wondering where I can find the parquet version of the flowers dataset on databricks. FYI I am working on the community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dataset was converted into Delta format, so path right now is `/databricks-datasets/flowers/delta`, instead of `/databricks-datasets/flowers/parquet`, and you need to read it with the corresponding code:

```py
df = spark.read.format('delta').load('/databricks-datasets/flowers/delta')
```

P.S. You can always use `%fs ls path` command to see what files are at given path

P.P.S. I'll ask to fix that notebook if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

label_index is removed from the dataset. You can recreate is as followed

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="label_index") 
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```